# How secure is ISA Server 2000

Tags: security, firewall, isa-server, windows-sbs

We have a small office using ISA Server 2000, previously this was connected to the internet through another firewall provided by the business park we are at, but soon will be connected directly to the internet. Is this a high security risk given its age, with all patches installed, will it still give adequate protection until next summer when it goes EOL and we have to upgrade the small business server or is it a high risk that would need immediate attention. This is a standard office with no internet servers attached.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe. I would sleep easy.  Just install all the patches.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no problems keeping your ISA in place as long as it is properly configured and updated.